# Count the rows on table php

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, row

I build ranking page and I want to add number for each row
can I do that?

I want to count the table there.
I am new with PHP.

```
// Showing Ranking list
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `userpoint`,`users` WHERE `users`.ID= `userpoint`.uID ORDER BY upoint DESC LIMIT 0, 30";
//Get Username by text
$username= "SELECT * FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `userpoint` on userpoint.uid = users.ID ";
$link_address= "http://***.co.il/profile/?username=";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table  class='grid_3 grid_5' style='width: 400px; position: absolute; margin-right: 600px;'>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th style='text-align: right;'>#</th>";
                echo "<th style='text-align: right;'>Name</th>";
                echo "<th style='text-align: right;'>Points</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $userlogin = $row[user_login];
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>#</td>";
                echo "<td>  <a href='$link_address$userlogin'> " . $row['display_name'] . "</td></a>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['upoint'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Add a number in here `echo "<td>#</td>";`?

Comment: yea but its gonna be the same number in all rows

Comment: Same number over and over again? Not incremental? What number?

Comment: @LielDahan, that's why you use a variable and increment it in the loop.  I suggest you start reading up on the basics of programming.

Comment: i have table and iwant it will be 1/2/3/4/5/....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a counter variable `$i` and set it prior to the `while()` loop.

Then place `$i` wherever you need your numeric (counter) value in your loop.

`$i++` increments the counter on each iteration. Read on more incremental values in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

```
$i = 1; // set the counter's start point
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $userlogin = $row[user_login];
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>#" . $i . "</td>";
        echo "<td>  <a href='$link_address$userlogin'> " . $row['display_name'] . "</td></a>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['upoint'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++; // here the counter gets increased by 1, so the following iteration it will be $i + 1
}
```

Now on each iteration of the loop, your page will show the following (pseudo) result:

```
#1
#2
#3
#4
etc...
```

Wherever `$i` is present.

Comment: Thanks alot sorry for my english (: